# Location headers in Laravel

Tags: php, redirect, header, location, laravel

I'm working with a Library for my university's authentication system (Ucam_Webauth) which means I have to redirect to the authentication server in one of the methods. Unfortunately, I cannot return a `Redirect:to()` because of the architecture of this library. The library itself uses `header('Location: ...');` but this isn't working for some reason.

If I make the programme `die();` after sending the header it works, but otherwise it doesn't.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 13):

```
return redirect()->to('url')->send();
```

Sends HTTP headers and content. In my application, send() method acts like 'exit()'  and is testable

Comment: While this code may work, but it is good to explain it a little.

Comment: This works perfectly. When you check the implementation of `Response::send()` in `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`, Laravel seems to clear all operations that could run after a header redirect. A header redirect often fails when there are lines of code after the header redirect is declared.

Comment: Thanks only it got me relief from error of "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I follow. Laravel sets the Location header as part of the Redirect::to() method. If you want to more explicitly define the response you could do it like this.

```
return Response::make( '', 302 )->header( 'Location', $url );
```

If that doesn't work I'd probably just fall back on the php stdlib header() and return null.

If all of this still doesn't do any good, maybe the profiler is messing things up. If it is turned on, try disabling it in the config.

Comment: Basically the `header()` wasn't working without killing the execution with `die()`. I fixed it by partially rewriting the library to work with Laravel's method. I would still be curious to know if there were a way to set the `Location` header without having to return a `Response`, since calling `header('Location: ...');` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
return Redirect::to('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, For this route:

```
Route::get('hello', array('as' => 'hello_name', 'uses' => 'HelloController@getHello'));
```

In laravel, you can redirect to url simply using

```
return Redirect::to('hello');
```

Alternatively, you can redirect to named route simply using

```
return Redirect::route('hello_name');
```