# Laravel Routing - Subdomain filtering

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and I'd like to filter the subdomain.

#### web.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{city}.localhost'], function () {

    if ($city does not exist in database) {rediret to localhost};
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');

});
```

#### What I'd like

If `subdomain` exists in the database continue. Otherwise redirect to the same address but without a subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using middleware to interrogate the $request URL and redirect accordingly, much like the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware does.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckSubdomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // check $request->url() here...
        if ($notInDatabase) {
            return redirect()->route('/somewhere');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like the `middleware` idea. I managed to do something but when `return redirect()->route('/somewhere')` the `url` in the browser stays the same. If I put `hello.example.com` and `hello` is not a city, I'm well redirect but the `url` is still `hello.example.com` instead of `example.com`

Comment: I tried `if($city->isEmpty()) {
            $newURL = 'example.com';
            header('Location: '.$newURL);
        }` but I get `ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156:
Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Check some of the answers here, might be something to get you running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643718/location-headers-in-laravel